# I cannot Alt+click on anything, and it's not moving windows

Tags: 20.04, gnome

I have been trying to Alt+click on things for a while, but when I hold Alt, the pointer becomes the regular arrow and clicking does not do anything, nothing at all.

I checked window dragging using dconf editor (`org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.mouse-button-modifier`), and it is set to `<Super>`.

How can I trace/fix this?

Ubuntu 20.04.4